# automatically calculate string mathematical expressing in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# string which is representation of a mathematical expression, something like this:

```
A = (B*0.25)+(D*0.25)+(1-W)
```

how can I calculate value of A? should I manually parse all characters, then perform my calculation? Although it is possible but I think it would be time-consuming to write such a code, is there any way that C# can understand this string and calculate value of A (of course I would declare A, B, D & W as variables

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/8426218/677014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't such a thing in .net itself, but if you have just primary operations you can parse input string and find related values, for this you can use [shunting yard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm) algorithm or [reverse polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), but also you can use [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) for more complicated scenarios.